# Trying to Scroll inside a div with selenium, scroller function only scrolls up to a certain amount and then just stops

Tags: python, selenium

I want to get a list of all the list items which are present inside a div with a scroller. They are not loaded at once upon loading the page, rather the items are loaded dynamically as the user scrolls down (until there are no elements left). So, this is the scroller script which I tried to implement:

```
def scroller():
    userList = None
    prev = 0    

    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        userList = WebDriverWait(browser, 50).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(( By.CLASS_NAME, '<class of list item>' ))
        )
        n = len(userList)
        if n == prev:
            break
        prev = n
        #getting the last element in the list in the view
        userList[-1].location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

This function scrolls the list upto a certain length, but doesn't go to the full length of the elements (not even half). Can someone please suggest a better way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to get the url?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan I'm trying to get a list of all users from my slack workspace. <MY_WORKSPACE>.slack.com/admin   are you familiar with the interphase?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan It's basically the same as Instagram's infinite scroll which loads new elements as soon as you reach the bottom. I've also tried using `browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", userList[-1])` instead of `userList[-1].location_once_scrolled_into_view` but it's the same result